# Defining ENV variables in a Dockerfile that is used in a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My situation is the following, I have a project with this structure:

```
project/
|
|______docker-compose.yml
|______database/
       |______Dockerfile
|______webapp/
       |______Dockerfile
```

My problem is with the `database` container build. My `database/Dockerfile` is the following:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.3
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=clients
EXPOSE 3306
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
database-server:
  build: ./database
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
```

So as you see above, I defined my `ENV` variables (`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_DATABASE`) in my `Dockerfile`, so I expect them to be used during the build when I use `docker-compose`. But they don't!

My `ENV` variables only get used when I build the container manually in `project/database` using the `Dockerfile` and the `docker build` command.

```
Dockerfile
|
|
| [Variables are available here]
|
|
docker-compose.yml
|
|
| [Variables are NOT available here]
|
docker run
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do? I want to define everything relative to a specific container in it's `Dockerfile`, and keep the `docker-compose.yml` to define the relationships and links between the containers.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As asked by @Tim, here is the output of my `docker-compose up`:

```
Starting root_database-server_1 ... done
Starting root_webapp_1 ... done
Attaching to root_database-server_1, root_webapp_1
database-server_1  | error: database is uninitialized and password option is         not specified
database-server_1  |   You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
...
... Rest of the log is fine..
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you give the output of `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are passing the variables?

Comment: @TimWolla, thanks for the reply, I added the output.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş I am putting them in the `Dockerfile` and then using it in the `docker-compose`. When I do a `docker-compose up`. They are not taken in consideration from the `Dockerfile`. I don't want to put them in the `docker-compose.yml`.. is it possible?

Comment: @user3426711 Could it be that it is starting an outdated docker image?

Comment: Oh I got your question now. Well, just a thought but what if you treated them like strings and put them between brackets? 

Still, it is not wise to embed passwords into images as environment variables. You can find them using `docker inspect -f "{{ .Config.Env }}" | grep <envName>` Take a look and see if they are really empty or the problem is something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect docker-compose is using an older image than the updated image you are expecting. Try this:

`docker-compose down` to stop and remove any existing containers being used in the stack. You can use `docker-compose rm` if everything is already stopped.

`docker-compose build` to make docker-compose rebuild everything with a build direction in the yml file.

`docker-compose up` to restart your stack. docker-compose should pick up the newly-built `database-server` image with the ENV set.

Comment: Sir, you are right and your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to build a local image for just that purpose.

```
version: '3'

services:

   database-server:
     image: mysql:8.0.3
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: clients
```

It's better documented and easier to maintain.

Comment: OP wants to keep configuration in the Dockerfile and only use docker-compose to define relationship between containers. However, this is how I would do it as well, nice and clean. +1

Comment: Thank for the answer, I know this but my use case is just an example. I want to know if it's possible to encapsulate everything container-related in the `Dockerfile` and only keep the `docker-compose.yml` for architecture description.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use them like this:
version: "3"
services:
database-server:
  build: ./database
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_VARIABLE_FOR_DOCKER_ENV=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_DATABASE_VARIABLE_FOR_DOCKER_ENV=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
```

Update: 
In your case you can easily do:

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_VARIABLE_FOR_DOCKER_ENV=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  - MYSQL_DATABASE_VARIABLE_FOR_DOCKER_ENV=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
```

However, keeping them in the docker compose is neater, as Andreas said. unless these values will change frequently. I doubt it that's the case with passwords though